# How to handle Ajax data with Mobx?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, mobx

I am playing around with mobx and wondering how do format data from the server to be match with the mobx classes? This of course would be done through an ajax request to grab the data.

```
  class Student {
            @observable firstName
            @observable lastName
            @observable classes = []

            constructor(firstName, lastName, classes) {
                this.firstName = firstName;
                this.lastName = lastName;
                this.classes = classes;
            }
        }

     class Classes {
            @observable name
            @observable number

            constructor(name, number) {
                this.name= name;
                this.number= number;
            }
        }

    class Container {
        @observable students = [];
    }
```

I am using SalesForce, so my backend is Java like, and I wondering do I have to make it into json? then on the client side build the classes with the data?

Or is there a more stream lined way I can do this?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of response you expect?

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice addon to MobX - [Serializr](https://github.com/mobxjs/serializr) that does exactly what you need - serializes JS class instances into JS objects (that later on can be converted to JSON strings) and the other way around.